# It cannot do this, "can it?"

Tags: questions

I think we can say:

> Technology XY doesn't work with batteries, *does it?*

to ask the other person for confirmation / to ask if you're correct or not.

**But how to do the same with a sentence with *cannot*:**

> This device cannot communicate with the protocol Y, *can it?*

Is this ending "can it" correct? I rarely here it.

Meaning I'm looking for: "it cannot communicate with ..., please correct me if I'm wrong"

Comment: Why would you not be able to use "can it" in this sense?

Comment: @HotLicks I don't know, but I think I never heard anyone saying "... cannot ..., can it?"

Comment: That's probably because they would use "can't" in informal use.

Comment: it's not about the first part cannot / can't, but more the end "can it?" that I did not know if it's used on everyday oral  language or not?

Comment: It is indeed part of everyday language.  There's a stackexchange called ELL that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with *does it vs. doesn't it* or *can it vs. can't it* can be problematic, since different languages handle negation differently.

Another option when trying to confirm a statement is:

> Technology XY doesn't work with batteries, **right**?
>   This device cannot communicate with the protocol Y, **right**?

Outside of formal contexts this should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

The ending "can it?" is completely correct in this case, and its meaning is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* it is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these examples are correct standard native grammar.

Another way is to turn this into a simple question e.g.

"Does technology XY work with batteries?"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).